# Connect Thumbor with AWS - s3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, thumbor

I have a bucket with photos on AWS.

When I try to access the photo url {photoUrl = https://aws-name-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/photo.jpg} in browser I got 'access denied'.

When I create link with thumbor,

```
Thumbor thumbor = Thumbor.create(getResources().getString(R.string.thumbor_sever));

final String newUrl = thumbor.buildImage(photoUrl).resize(48, 48).toUrl();
```

and try to load it with Picasso, I got a '404 Not Found'.

If I replace photoUrl from aws with http://www.rizwanashraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/redrose7-wallpaper.jpg  it is working.

I don't know how to, somehow, connect   Thumbor server with AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html) you have to give permission to view/read files from your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ready to use Thumbor S3 Docker Image which allows you to integrate with AWS
https://github.com/beeyev/thumbor-s3-docker